# Problem with Noto sans Devanagari

Tags: xetex

I am using texlive 2020 in windows 10. I am trying to use Noto Sans Devanagari font with xelatex. I have the fonts in my texmf-local as well as in C:\windows\fonts.  I can load the engish Noto fonts without using the file name. But, xelatex is unable to find the Noto Sans Devanagari font if I do not use the file name. If I use the file name it works fine as in
the following mwe.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\eng}{Noto Serif}
\setmainfont{NotoSansDevanagari-Regular.ttf}%
[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=velthuis]
\setsansfont{Noto Sans}
\catcode`\~=12
\begin{document}
    parik.saa ph~orm bharane se pahale satriiya kaarya jamaa karanaa anivaarya hai|

    {\eng This is a test.}\\
    {\eng\sffamily\bfseries This is a test.}
\end{document}
```

But this MWE does not work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\eng}{Noto Serif}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans Devanagari}%
[Script=Devanagari, Mapping=velthuis]
\setsansfont{Noto Sans}
\catcode`\~=12
\begin{document}
    parik.saa ph~orm bharane se pahale satriiya kaarya jamaa karanaa anivaarya hai|

    {\eng This is a test.}\\
    {\eng\sffamily\bfseries This is a test.}
\end{document}
```

Xelatex does not seem to have problems with english fonts  even if I don't use file name as in Noto Sans and Noto Serif.  But it has a problem with Noto Sans Devanagari.  What can be the  problem?
**Added**
The command

```
otfinfo -i f:/texmf-local-from-linux/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSansDevanagari-Regular.ttf
```

gives

```
Family:              Noto Sans Devanagari
Subfamily:           Regular
Full name:           Noto Sans Devanagari Regular
PostScript name:     NotoSansDevanagari-Regular
Version:             Version 2.000;GOOG;noto-source:20170915:90ef993387c0; ttfautohint (v1.7)
Unique ID:           2.000;GOOG;NotoSansDevanagari-Regular
Description:         Designed by Monotype design team.
Designer:            Jelle Bosma - Monotype Design Team
Designer URL:        http://www.monotype.com/studio
Manufacturer:        Monotype Imaging Inc.
Vendor URL:          http://www.google.com/get/noto/
Trademark:           Noto is a trademark of Google Inc.
Copyright:           Copyright 2015 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
License URL:         http://scripts.sil.org/OFL
License Description: This Font Software is licensed under the SIL Open Font License, Version 1.1. This Font Software is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the SIL Open Font License for the specific language, permissions and limitations governing your use of this Font Software.
Vendor ID:           GOOG
```

Comment: Try `\setmainfont{Noto Sans Devanagari Regular}` as there are many faces and weights in this family.

Comment: @Ross  This does not work.
'''
! Package fontspec Error: The font "Noto Sans Devanagari Regular" cannot be
(fontspec)                found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 [Script=Devanagari, Mapping=velthuis]
'''

Comment: Works for me. Check that the fonts are installed in `C:\Windows\fonts`. You need to `install for all users` otherwise they will go under `\user\appdata`.

Comment: @Ross I don't know what the problem is.  The font files are in C:\Windows\Fonts for use with microsoft word. I have checked this again now.  Since xelatex could'nt find the files  I copied the fonts to texmf-local tree.  It works with file names, but not font names.

Comment: You should avoid to have the fonts in two places, xelatex can get easily confused. I just installed the current version in C:\Windows\fonts on my system, and xelatex had no problems with `\setmainfont{Noto Sans Devanagari}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer No good. I removed the fonts from the texmf-local tree, ran texhash.  I updated texlive. The mwe did not compile even with file names.  Could it have something to do with the latest windows 10 update that is problematic? I went back to square one. I have installed the fonts again in my local-texmf tree.

Comment: did you really installed in c:\windows\fonts? windows allows now fonts installations in user accounts too and I don't know if xelatex can find fonts there. What happens if you use lualatex? Does it find the font?

Comment: I found that lualatex takes the fonts for which I have used the file names from the texmf-local and the fonts for which I use font names from c:/Users/s_ven/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Fonts. I have copied the fonts to c:\Windows\Fonts, but this does not seem enough to install the fonts for all users.  I selected the fonts, right clicked and chose install for all users.  It works in xelatex now with font  names.